# golang database/sql using pq

Tags: go, pq

I'm having this issue

```
 db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=xxx dbname=xxx connect_timeout=5 sslmode=disable")
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
 }
```

I have no postgres installed on my localhost so sql.Open should return some error but actually it is not until I try to prepare a query and finally I get a connection refused error

```
stmt, err := c.DB.Prepare("SELECT id FROM services WHERE name = $1")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

is this an expected behaviour? or I'm missing something...

Comment: Yes, see related question: [How do I handle opening/closing Db connection in a Go app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587008/how-do-i-handle-opening-closing-db-connection-in-a-go-app/40587071#40587071)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open), **Yes** it is an expected behavior. Open() does not directly open a connection to the database.
Instead the first connection is opened when the database is actually used the first time.

```
Open may just validate its arguments without creating a connection 
to the database. 
To verify that the data source name is valid, call Ping.
```

Use [Ping()](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=14097:14123#L489) to check if the connection is valid or not.

Comment: thanks sadil I should read the documentation with more patience!