# Referring to an open database connection inside a function - Golang

Tags: sql, database, go

My main function opens a database connection:

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./house.db")
    checkErr(err)

    ...
}
```

Then, I want to create a function that allows me to add a row to the database based on a passed struct:

```
func addRow(row Room) error {
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO Rooms (Name, Size, WindowCount, WallDecorationType, Floor) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    _, err = stmt.Exec(row.Name , row.Size , row.WindowCount , row.WallDecorationType , row.Floor)
    return err
}
```

But obviously I can't do that because the `addRow()` function has no idea what `db` is.

How would I make this function work? Should I perhaps, open the database outside of the main function?

Comment: Can't you pass `db` in as parameter?

Comment: Use a global `db` or pass it as a paramter.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [How do I handle opening/closing Db connection in a Go app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587008/how-do-i-handle-opening-closing-db-connection-in-a-go-app/40587071#40587071)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on how your application works, you can either

1. keep the `db` **global**
2. pass `db` as a **parameter**
3. make `addRoom` a **method**

What I typically do for API services is create a **global** `db`, like this:

```
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error
    db, err = sql.Open("sqlite3", "./house.db")
    checkErr(err)
    // create room Room{}
    err = addRoom(room)
    checkErr(err)
}
```

But you can also pass db as a **parameter**:

```
func addRow(db *sql.DB, row Room) error
```

Or you can create a **`struct`** which keeps the connection as an attribute and makes `addRow` a method:

```
type dbConn struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func (conn dbConn) addRow(row Room) error
```

This [book](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/05.3.html) has some nice examples.